# Access site requiring login an self-signed cert with Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

If I want to connect to a site which requires basic authentication and also uses a self signed cert I create a `CredentialsProvider` which then lets me access the site.

If I want to access a site which uses a self signed cert I use the `sslContextBuilder` and allow all certs to be used.

Each of the both work on their own but when I try to put them together to access a site that requires login and uses a self signed cert it wont let me.

I'm sure this is just simple syntax but how do I do this?

```
 CloseableHttpClient hc = HttpClients.custom()
      .setSslcontext(sslcb.build())
      .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
      .build();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, what *exactly* is your problem? Do you get an exception or a compilation error?

Comment: Additionally it would probably be useful to mention  that this is an issue with the Apache HttpClient library. Again welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try `setSSLSocketFactory` instead of `setSslcontext`

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
    .build();
```

Comment: Yea thanks Id upvote your answer but I cant. That was it in the end :)